# How do I add a timestamp when digitally signing a file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, digital-signature

I tried to implement in .NET C# an utility similar to signtool.exe.
To digitally sign a file, I used the classes SignedCms and CmsSigner.

```
CmsSigner signer;
...
SignedCms content = 
    new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(File.ReadAllBytes(aFileToSign)));
content.ComputeSignature(signer, true);
```

However, I am not sure how to add a timestamp received from a time server.
signtool.exe has the option

```
signtool sign /t "time server url" ...
```

One possibility seems to consist in using Pkcs9SigningTime class, but I don't know how to use it correctly in conjuction with a timestamp server. All of the examples use Pkcs9SigningTime and the current time of the system. With a time server, it may be more complicated because the time server has its own certificate, and the answer will contain the time and a hash used as a countersignature.

Can anyone provide some clues about that?

Comment: I don't think the fact that the time server signs its time is relevant - it's to prove to _you_ its identity, it doesn't prove anything to your users since you could hold the timestamp for arbitrarily long before applying it.

Comment: Would using Bouncy Castle be an option? I could explain it there.

Comment: Bouncy Castle can be an option. It supports RFC3161 but I am not sure that it can help with Authenticode(tm) timestamp protocol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Authenticode(tm) timestamp protocol predates the Time-Stamp Protocol defined in [RFC3161](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3161.txt). However (and IIRC) there is no direct support for asking a timestamp built in .NET.

So you can either:

1. build a TSP client to get your timestamps; or
2. piggyback the existing *free* timestamp servers that are around for code signing.

While I would suggest #1 in most cases (it's a standard and more future proof) I'm not sure if there are C# libraries available that supports that today.

If you're interested in #2 then I know (because I've written it ;-) that the [code is  available](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/tools/security/signcode.cs) inside Mono (MIT.X11 licensed) to support Authenticode(tm) and code signing (including timestamping).

Comment: Sugestion to have a look at Mono code is very valuable for reference. For now, I think that I will use the Win32 API SignerSignEx, SignerTimeStampEx called via P/Invoke.